# Count distinct elements in an list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to count all the distinct numbers of a list.For example if my list consist of {1,2,1,1,3,4} i need to return 4.Here is the code i have written.

```
struct Node 
{ 
  int data; 
  struct Node *next; 
}; 
typedef struct Node Node_t;



int count_distinct(Node_t * start) 
{ 
    Node_t  *ptr1, *ptr2; 
    ptr1 = start; 
    int counter=0;
    /* pick one element*/
    while (ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next != NULL) 
    { 
        ptr2 = ptr1; 
  
        /* compare picked element with the rest */
        while (ptr2->next != NULL) 
        { 
            /* If duplicate */
            if (ptr1->data == ptr2->next->data) 
            { 
                break;
            } 
            else 
                ptr2 = ptr2->next; 
                counter++;
        } 
        ptr1 = ptr1->next; 
    } 
return counter;
}
```

Comment: Asking the same question twice won't get you any further.

Comment: I asked the same question cause i didnt get an answer.

Comment: Just be patient.

Comment: why don't you dry run the program on a pen and paper?